# Entity Framework Core metadata is different than model and DB. How to refresh?

Tags: refresh, entity-framework-core, database-metadata, modelmetadata

I'm new to using EF but it was relatively simple to implement for me, the problem came when I need to change the model. I created a column that I later deleted. However, at runtime the ghost column is causing an Invalid column error.

I have added this method to my context to confirm my suspicion.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            bool destroy = false;
            foreach (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Property p in modelBuilder.Entity<File>().Metadata.GetProperties())
            {
                if (p.Name == "AppointmentID")
                {
                    destroy = true;
                }
            }
}
```

I have tried to use framework core migration tools, adding and removing colums. That works great, but none of this gets rid of the reference to an old column.

Is there a way to reset this? It seems older versions of EF had physical files that were generated as the schemas/definitions of the columns. Is there something like that I could force to be refreshed?

Comment: This looks like a foreign key column required by EF to map a reference navigation property...

Comment: Thank you @bricelam. How would one address that issue?